# How to get custom option values of the product in Magento?

Tags: php, magento-1.9

How to get the `custom option values` of the product in *Magento 1.9.0.1?*

Let us consider I have a `custom option`:

> Title: Flavour
>      sku: flavour
>      input type: drop-down box
>      values: vanilla, strawberry, chocolate, pista

I have to get the `values` of the `Flavour` only, ie, `vanilla, strawberry, chocolate and pista` only.

How to get these values? This same product may contain other custom options like color, etc, but it doesn't matter.

I have to store these `flavour` values in a array for further use.

I am working in this page:

> app/design/frontend/yourtheme/yourtheme/template/catalog/product/view/options/type/select.phtml

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below mentioned code for getting the option value on product page here $product is product object and you can generate the dropdown html from this code.

```
if($product->hasOptions()) {
foreach($product->getOptions() as $o){
    $optionType = $o->getType();
    if ($optionType == 'drop_down') {
        $values = $o->getValues();
        foreach ($values as $v) {
            print_r($v->getTitle());
        }
    }else{
        print_r($o);
    }
}}
```

in select.phtml you can get the $_option object use below mentioned code for get the option values there.

```
 $values = $_option->getValues();
 foreach ($values as $v) {
    print_r($v->getTitle());
 }
```

Comment: the options values are required in select.phtml , not on product page, How will u get the product object in select.phtml.?

Comment: in select.phtml you can get the $_option object use below mentioned code for get the option values there.

$values = $_option->getValues();
foreach ($values as $v) {
 print_r($v->getTitle());
}